# PDF has no file extension .pdf when generated with visualforce

Tags: visualforce, pdf

I am generating a pdf invoice with visualforce, but when it downloads there is no file extension. I have read other questions on SE and tried to simplify the content. Right now the code is simplified to

```
<apex:page standardController="Invoice__c" renderAs="pdf">

   hello

</apex:page>
```

and the file extension is still not added to the file.

Comment: What browser is it?

Comment: I use firefox 24.2.0

Comment: Are you on the beta programme for PDF2?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the name and extension of the PDF explicitly as follows, for example

```
Apexpages.currentPage().getHeaders().put('content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=AccountReport.pdf');
```

Unfortunately this is directly not supported in  tag in Visualforce.